# I want to re-arrange a file in an order in shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I have a file test.txt like below spaces in between each record

```
service[1.1],parttion, service[1.2],parttion, service[1.3],parttion, service[2.1],parttion, service2[2.2],parttion,
```

Now I want to rearrange it as below into a output.txt

```
COMPOSITES=parttion/service/1.1,parttion/service/1.2,parttion/service/1.3,parttion/service/2.1,parttion/service/2.2
```

I've tried:

```
final_str=''
  COMPOSITES=''
# Re-arranging the composites and preparing the composite property file
  while read line; do
  partition_val="$(echo $line | cut -d ',' -f 2)"
  composite_temp1_val="$(echo $line | cut -d ',' -f 1)"
  composite_val="$(echo $composite_temp1_val | cut -d '[' -f 1)"
  version_temp1_val="$(echo $composite_temp1_val | cut -d '[' -f 2)"
  version_val="$(echo $version_temp1_val | cut -d ']' -f 1)"
  final_str="$partition_val/$composite_val/$version_val,"
  COMPOSITES=$COMPOSITES$final_str
  done <./temp/test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

We start with the file:

```
$ cat test.txt
service[1.1],parttion, service[1.2],parttion, service[1.3],parttion, service[2.1],parttion, service2[2.2],parttion,
```

We can rearrange that file as follows:

```
$ awk -F, -v RS=" " 'BEGIN{printf "COMPOSITES=";} {gsub(/[[]/, "/"); gsub(/[]]/, ""); if (NF>1) printf "%s%s/%s",NR==1?"":",",$2,$1;}' test.txt
COMPOSITES=parttion/service/1.1,parttion/service/1.2,parttion/service/1.3,parttion/service/2.1,parttion/service2/2.2
```

The same command split over multiple lines is:

```
awk -F, -v RS=" " '
BEGIN{
    printf "COMPOSITES=";
}

{


    gsub(/[[]/, "/")
    gsub(/[]]/, "")
    if (NF>1) printf "%s%s/%s",NR==1?"":",",$2,$1
}
' test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with.

```
awk -F '[],[]' -v RS=" " 'BEGIN{printf("COMPOSITES=")}/../{printf("%s/%s/%s,",$4,$1,$2);}' test.txt
```

Broken out for easier reading:

```
awk -F '[],[]' -v RS=" " '
  BEGIN {
    printf("COMPOSITES=");
  }
  /../ {
    printf("%s/%s/%s,",$4,$1,$2);
  }' test.txt
```

More detailed explanation of the script:

- `-F '[],[]'` - use commas or square brackets as field separators
- `-v RS=" "` - use just the space as a record separator
- `'BEGIN{printf("COMPOSITES=")}` - starts your line
- `/../` - run the following code on any line that has at least two characters. This avoids the empty field at the end of a line terminating with a space.
- `printf("%s/%s/%s,",$4,$1,$2);` - print the elements using a `printf()` format string that matches the output you specified.

As concise as this is, the format string *does* leave a trailing comma at the end of the line. If this is a problem, it can be avoided with a bit of extra code.

---

You could also do this in sed, if you like writing code in line noise.

```
sed -e 's:\([^[]*\).\([^]]*\).,\([^,]*\), :\3/\1/\2,:g;s/^/COMPOSITES=/;s/,$//' test.txt
```

---

Finally, if you want to avoid external tools like sed and awk, you can do this in bash alone:

```
a=($(<test.txt))
echo -n "COMPOSITES="
for i in "${a[@]}"; do
  i="${i%,}"
  t="${i%]*}"
  printf "%s/%s/%s," "${i#*,}" "${i%[*}" "${t#*[}"
done
echo ""
```

This slurps the contents of test.txt into an array, which means your input data *must* be separated by whitespace, per your example.  It then adds the prefix, then steps through the array, using **Parameter Expansion** to massage the data into the fields you need.  The last line (`echo ""`) is helpful for testing; you may want to eliminate it in practice.